# SailsJs does not compile HTML

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I tried creating a simple application with SailsJs. When i run sails lift the server is running, but the HTML is not compiled for some reason; therefore I get an empty HTML file.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Some sample code will help

Comment: Which file exactly. All code was generated with sails generator. I have not edited anything yet, therefore it should work i assume.

Comment: Are you saying you ran `sails new` to get a new app, ran `sails lift` to get the server running, saw the sailboat in your console, went to `http://localhost:1337` and got an empty page?

Comment: Yes, the server is running, but when i visit http://localhost:1337, I get an empty page. I have windows 7 64 bit, in case.

Comment: does your console give you any output when you go to that page? Does the browser complete the page load or does it hang?